Inherit at once vs. inherit one by one
#Senario:
(1)  let's say there is a chain of inheritence like this (the later in turn inherit from the preceding one):
parent->child1->child2->child3->...->child_n; 

(2) And so we have data layout of each of them:
parent: DATA 
child1: DATA1 = DATA + extra1
child2: DATA2 = DATA1 + extra2  = DATA +extra1,2
...
chidl_n: DATA_n = DATA_n-1 + extra_n = DATA + extra1,2,..., n 

(3) And then create a class inherit from them all at once:
 MyClass: public parent, child1, child2, child3, ..., child n;

Question: What is the data layout of MyClass should be?
A. Just like "chidl_n" above?
B. Different from "child_n" , if so what is it, and how its data are organized in memory?
-------------------------EDIT:
I'm sorry to bother a lot. But I have a direct relevant question after reading the answer.
For child_n, it is easy to Cast To any of its parents (parent, child 1,...,child_n-1), because they share the same starting address.
However so far I know, from MyClass we can also Cast To any of its parents too (parent, child 1,...,child_n) even if they didn't share the same address according to the answer.
I wonder how it is managed and handled to return a specific subobject of MyClass since they didn't share the same starting address.
Did they store a lot of starting addresses for each subclass? or Will they only perform the address calculation whenever the cast is evaluated?

Question back: why do you care how it is organized into memory? The end result is that all inherited members are accessible.

It will be probably different than chidl_n, but this is an implementation detail you should not rely on in any way when you write code.

@Botje To be honest, I dont have a particular reason, I just feel like it is important to know :)

@wohlstad , hm...I guess 'MyClass' will occupy very much in memory, like 'n times of DATA' and a lot of recursive extra_i :)

@Crackie if you are curious about a specific implementation, you can write a small test program and inspect the layout in the debugger (it's easy with VS that you mentioned in the title).

perhaps any one can verify that MyClass will have only one 'DATA' or 'n times of DATAs' would be a great help for now :)

because I think if we try to access DATA in some way, and there is more than one copy of DATAs I could access an unintended DATA :)

You can easily find out what the layout is by inspecting. Your tools for that would be a debugger, the sizeof operator, and the << stream operator overload for void pointers.

The data layout will depend on the machine architecture, the compiler, the compiler version and any layout affecting flags.  The layout will vary greatly between, say, a 6502 platform and a DS9k platform.  The best way to find out is to inspect the generated code.

Each base class is associated with a sub-object in instances of the derived class.
So MyClass will transitively have n+1 parent subobjects, n child_1 subobjects, n-1 child_2 subobjects, ..., 1 child_n subobject.
Each of those subobjects will have their own data members.
If you had instead inherited virtually everywhere, there would only be one subobject of parent and each of the child classes.
How they are laid out in memory is dependant on the implementation, but it will commonly be for each class; first all of the first base , followed by all of the next base, ..., and finally all of the non-static data members defined in the class, in the order they are defined.

It is definitely the answer I'm looking for. Much appreciate! thank a lot @Caleth :)

I'm sorry to bother a lot. But I have a side relevant question. For child_n, it is easy to Cast To any of its parents (parent, child1,...child_n-1), because they share the same starting address.
However so far I know, from MyClass we can also Cast To any of its parents too (parent, child1,...child_n) even they didn't share the same address according to the answer. I wonder how it is managed and handled to return the sub object of MyClass. Because they didn't share the same starting address :)

@Crackie The cast adds whatever offset is necessary to the pointer value. In the case of the first base class the offset is 0

Thanks for answering, I guess it has to store the array of GLOBAL offset values from beginning. So that it can iterate over each starting point to check the data if it matches the casted-to type? Otherwise it would take a long time the Cast operation to be done?

('GLOBAL' because there could be another GLOBAL direct sub-object of MyClass, that indirectly contain LOCAL sub of sub-object match the size of casted-to size too.)

ah! I guess I figure it out. At the time of constructing MyClass object, each sub-object also has its local starting address and its local size by the C++ implementation. And When the cast starts it will iterate over each starting address and the associate size until it finishes and decide if there is any matching casted-to object?

@Crackie no, a static_cast is, at runtime, an addition by a constant, or nothing at all, if the constant is 0. A dynamic_cast might have to follow some pointers to know where a particular subobject starts.

I see. thanks for your help!
